# Runtime error 2115 afterupdate

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox that involves some values. I want to do this job:

If the user scroll this listbox and selects a value, a query runs and the result of the query should be shown in a text box. I have written this code as an `AfterUpdate` event of my listbox. But I get this error:

```
Private Sub List2_AfterUpdate()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT XValue, YValue,Wert FROM tb_DCM_Daten WHERE (FzgID=" & Forms!frm_fahrzeug!ID & " AND [Name]='" & List2.Value & "')")
  If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    If IsNull(rst.Fields("XValue").Value) Then
      Text10.SetFocus
      Text10.Text = "-"
    End If
  Else
  MsgBox "The record set is empty"
  End If
End Sub
```

How can I solve this problem?
Is there a better way to do this job?

Comment: Is `Text10` bound to a field in the form's Record Source?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with _Click() event of listbox ?